# Remove select option based on the current year variable value

Tags: jquery

In my script below I would like to replace "2014" with the value of my year variable i.e. "y"

I would like to remove all the options in a select box where the value is less than current year. The following script works fine all I need help is how to replace "2014" in my code with the current year value?

Thanks.

```
<script>

var d = new Date(),
n = d.getMonth()+1,
y = d.getFullYear();

$('.year option[value]').each(function() {
if( $(this).attr("value") < 2014 ) { $(this).remove(); };
});
</script>
```

Comment: I'm confused.  Why aren't you just using `y` instead of `2014` ?

Comment: Thanks devlin, I am beginner in javascript. I didnt know how to get the variable value.. You solved it all i need is y. I was using 'y' and it was not working

Answer (score 0):

You need to use document.ready before your script load as below code

```
<script>    
var d = new Date(),
    n = d.getMonth()+1,
    y = d.getFullYear();

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('.year option[value]').each(function() {
          var optionVal = jQuery(this).attr("value");    
          if( optionVal < y ) 
          { 
            jQuery(this).remove(); 
          };
        });
    });
</script>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jaydp13/ayhfoqnp/)